# What does 这样才不白来世上一回 mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the following sentence:

> 他说：“人往高处走，水往低处流。我没有满足的时候。没见识过的东西还多着呢。我什么都想试试，**这样才不白来世上一回**。”

I think the sentence means:

> He says: "People go higher, water flows into lower. I don't feel satisfied, have not seen everything yet. I want to see everything, ..."

But I don't understand the last part. Judged by the context, it might be something like the following:

> These could be experienced only once in the next life (...?)

Especially I don't understand what 白 means here. It might be "clear" (verb), but then the meaning would be:

> These could not be clear once in the next life (...?)

So what does it mean?

Comment: The last part means *not to come to this world in vain*. 白 means *in vain*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 我什么都想试试，**这样才不白来世上一回。**
>
> *I want to experience/try many things, only then will I feel like my life hasn't been wasted.*

That is the general meaning. As for the bolded part:

- 這樣才 - *only like/by doing this*, referring to 我什麽都想試試
- 白X - *a waste of effort to X*
- 來世上 - *be born into the world*
- 一回 - *one time*

來世上一回 is a figure of speech culturally referring to the possibility of reincarnation (being born multiple times). The idea is that coming into this world is a journey that takes effort, and while being here this person wants to experience as many things as possible.

Answer (score 3):

不白 not in vain

他说：“人往高处走，
He said: "People go upwards,
水往低处流。
water flows downwards
我没有满足的时候。
I don't have enough time.
没见识过的东西还多着呢。
There are many things I have not experienced.
我什么都想试试，
I want to try everything,
这样才不白来世上一回。”
only that way will this life not have been in vain.